# NSDate is not showing the expected result

Tags: ios, nsdate

I am working with NSDates and don't find explanation to following behaviour. May be another SO user's point of view can help me finding the reason for following behaviour.

This is part of my code:

```
        NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
        NSInteger comps = (NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit);

        NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
        NSDate *date = self.todoDueDate;

        NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
        [components setCalendar:calendar];
        [components setYear:2065];
        [components setMonth:11];
        [components setDay:12];

        NSDate *dateFuturoSomeday = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

        NSCalendar *calendar1 = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
        NSDateComponents *components1 = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
        [components setCalendar:calendar1];
        [components setYear:2065];
        [components setMonth:11];
        [components setDay:13];

        NSDate *dateFuturoCompleted = [calendar1 dateFromComponents:components1];         


        NSDateComponents *date1Components = [calendar components:comps
                                                        fromDate: today];
        NSDateComponents *date2Components = [calendar components:comps
                                                        fromDate: date];
        NSDateComponents *date3Components = [calendar components:comps
                                                        fromDate: dateFuturoSomeday];
        NSDateComponents *date4Components = [calendar components:comps
                                                        fromDate: dateFuturoCompleted];


        today = [calendar dateFromComponents:date1Components];
        date = [calendar dateFromComponents:date2Components];
        dateFuturoSomeday = [calendar dateFromComponents:date3Components];
        dateFuturoCompleted = [calendar dateFromComponents:date4Components];

        NSLog(@"DATE FUTURO SOMEDAY: %@", dateFuturoSomeday);
        NSLog(@"DATE FUTURO COMPLETED: %@", dateFuturoCompleted);
```

The problem is that for the log DATE FUTURO SOMEDAY, the result is:

`2065-11-12 07:00:00 +0000`

but for the log DATE FUTURO COMPLETED, the result is:

`0001-01-01 06:59:56 +0000` .

Why not

`2065-11-13 07:00:00 +0000`  ?

May be I am tired and can't see the issue.
Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made the typo while setting components.

See below lines:

```
NSCalendar *calendar1 = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
        NSDateComponents *components1 = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
        [components setCalendar:calendar1];
        [components setYear:2065];
        [components setMonth:11];
        [components setDay:13];
```

Here you allocated components1 but filling details in components. It should be:

```
NSCalendar *calendar1 = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
            NSDateComponents *components1 = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
            [components1 setCalendar:calendar1];
            [components1 setYear:2065];
            [components1 setMonth:11];
            [components1 setDay:13];
```

Comment: You were the first, thank you, I was breaking my brain with this for a couple of of hours.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `components` instead of `components1`. Use `components1` like in following snippet:

```
NSCalendar *calendar1 = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components1 = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[components1 setCalendar:calendar1];
[components1 setYear:2065];
[components1 setMonth:11];
[components1 setDay:13];
```

Hope it will work..!!

Comment: You were the second, thank you, but I guess I can only accept one answer. Thank you very much in any case, for your time and efforts.